# Tomcat/Jersey: client certificate authentication

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, authentication

I am developing a RESTful service using Jersey/Tomcat.

I need to support two sets of APIs public and private. Public APIs are open to all and are authenticated using API keys. Private APIs will be called only from my own WebServer layer to perform certain internal operations.

I prefer to host both sets of APIs on the same server so that I can manage/scale them efficiently.

```
The URIs for the APIs will look some thing like this:
    https://myapis/v1.0/*  --> for public APIs 
    and
    https://myapis/v1.0/secure/*  --> for public APIs
```

For security reasons, **I would like to authenticate the private APIs using client certificate**. ie, the web servers must call the secure/* APIs call with a self-signed certificate which is installed on Tomcat's trustStore.

Based on my research, I see that it can be achieved either by [using web.xml](http://blog.mafr.de/2011/04/17/excluding-pages-from-auth/) or [JAVA security Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#BABHABCC)

But in my case, neither works.

If I take the web.xml route ( I added a tomcat user in tomcat-user.xml based on the certificate attributes) **neither API are accessible (error 403)**

If I take the annotation route, both APIs can be accessed without authentication.

I came across several articles on the topic and I did several trial-and-error attempts. But none seems to work.

What is the right way to do it ?

Here is my web.xml

> jersey-serlvet
>           
>               com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
>           
>           
>                com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
>                com.mycompany.reststuff
>           
>           1
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/v1.0/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
>
> <security-constraint>
>     <web-resource-collection>
>         <web-resource-name>PuplicAPIs</web-resource-name>
>         <url-pattern>/v1.0/*</url-pattern>
>         <http-method>GET</http-method>
>         <http-method>POST</http-method>
>     </web-resource-collection>
>     <!-- no auth-constraint -->
> </security-constraint>
>
> <security-constraint>
>     <web-resource-collection>
>         <web-resource-name>PrivateAPIs</web-resource-name>
>         <url-pattern>/v1.0/secure/*</url-pattern>
>         <http-method>GET</http-method>
>         <http-method>POST</http-method>
>     </web-resource-collection>
>     <auth-constraint>
>          <role-name>WebCaller</role-name>    
>     </auth-constraint>
> </security-constraint>
>
> <security-role>
>   <role-name>WebCaller</role-name>
> </security-role>
> <login-config>
>   <auth-method>CLIENT-AUTH</auth-method>
> </login-config> ...
> ```

Comment: Did you open Tomcat SSL http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html?

Comment: This might be an obvious question but, did you add the tomcat user in tomcat-user.xml to the WebCaller role? A 403 (Forbidden) makes me think the authentication succeeded but the authenticated user is not authorized to access the resource.